# Show cart page in a popup on add to cart action

Tags: ajax, magento, popup, cart, magento-1.8

I'm trying to display the cart in a popup on the product detail page once the user clicks on the 'Add to cart' button.

I use a Ajax cart popup extension which displays a pop with option to continue shopping or go to the cart page after the user clicks on the add to cart button. Is it possible to show the cart contents in a popup similar to this?

I found that we can check the add to cart action with the event 'checkout_cart_add_product_complete'. Any ideas?